# A French flag with CSS in a single div?

Tags: html, css, semantics

The semantically correct HTML:

```
<div id="flag">
    <h1>French flag</h1>
</div>
```

With this only, how do a [French flag](http://www.flags.net/images/largeflags/FRAN0001.GIF) in pure CSS (ie 33% blue, 33% white, 33% red)?

I create a demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XdHxS/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could utilitize pseude elements: http://jsfiddle.net/XdHxS/4/

```
#flag {
    width: 99px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}

#flag:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #00f;
    width: 33%;
    z-index: 4;
}
#flag:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #f00;
    width: 33%;
    z-index: 4;
}

#flag h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #999;
    z-index: 16;
}
```

Comment: For a single div, we could also use a linear-gradient: `background: linear-gradient(to right, #005cbf 33.33%, #ffffff 33.33%, #ffffff 66.67%, #ef4135 66.67%);`

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/XdHxS/3/

```
#flag {
width: 99px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 25px;
border-top: 25px solid blue;
border-bottom: 25px solid red;
margin: 10px;
}

#flag h1 {
font-size: 12px;
color: #999;
display:block;
height:25px;
background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: The stripes in the French flag are horizontal, not vertical as in your example

Comment: Ha! You'd think I would know that...

Comment: lol you made my day. Nice border hack!

Comment: Useful for something like a German flag though!   :-)

Answer (score 2):

can't say that @grillz answer is wrong by any means, however this technique works as well, using content:, :before and :after. http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/XdHxS/5/